# wp localize script is not working in a custom AJAX request

Tags: wp-localize-script

I am trying to use `wp_localize_script()` to send some php values to a script.

The following are the part of the file `inc/show-event.php`.

```
if( $price ) {
    $pricefortwo    = ceil( ( 2 * $price) - ( 0.2 * $price ) );
    $savefortwo     = ( 2 * $price) - $pricefortwo;
    $priceforthree  = ceil( ( 3 * $price) - ( 0.333 * $price ) );
    $saveforthree   = ( 3 * $price) - $priceforthree;
    $priceforretake = ceil( 0.5 * $price );
    $saveforretake  = $price - $priceforretake;

    // Setting the session variables
    $_SESSION['price'] = $price;
    $_SESSION['price_for_two'] = $pricefortwo;
    $_SESSION['price_for_three'] = $priceforthree;
    $_SESSION['price_for_retake'] = $priceforretake;

    $session_array = array(
                'price'         => $_SESSION['price'],
                'price_for_two'     => $_SESSION['price_for_two'],
                'price_for_three'   => $_SESSION['price_for_three'],
                'price_for_retake'  => $_SESSION['price_for_retake']
            );
    wp_localize_script( 'init_show_calendar', 'session_param', $session_array );
}
```

After this when I try and use the object name `session_param` in `init_show_calendar.js` file it throws a js error saying `session_param` is not defined. but when i use the following code in `functions.php`.

```
$session_array = array(
                'price'         => $_SESSION['price'],
                'price_for_two'     => $_SESSION['price_for_two'],
                'price_for_three'   => $_SESSION['price_for_three'],
                'price_for_retake'  => $_SESSION['price_for_retake']
            );
wp_localize_script( 'init_show_calendar', 'session_param', $session_array );
```

it returns me the variable but it doesn't return the latest values, it returns the value stored in a page refresh.

FYI: The `show-event.php` is called in a plugin in the following way

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_event', array($this, 'render_frontend_modal'));
function render_frontend_modal() {
    require_once AEC_PATH . 'inc/show-event.php';
}
```

Please let me know if you want any more information.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're doing. You can't localize a script in an AJAX callback, it has to be localized in the request that outputs the script, after the script is enqueued but before it is output to the page.

Comment: @Milo I want to use the session variables in my js script, so tried pass it to the script using wp_localize, can i do it any other way?

Comment: `json_encode` your `$session_array` and return that from your ajax handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My need was to set different prices in the session and fetch those in my js script. I am using a **[jquery session plugin](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin)** to set and get session, but it wasn't getting session set by php, so I was trying to send variables using `wp_localize` and set it in the js script.

Taking the clue from @Milo, I passed the values using `json_encode` and set them to session at the ajax handler end.

This is what i did:--

`show-event.php` file

```
 $output = array(
        'price'         => $_SESSION['price'],
        'price_for_two'     => $_SESSION['price_for_two'],
        'price_for_three'   => $_SESSION['price_for_three'],
        'price_for_retake'  => $_SESSION['price_for_retake']
    );
    $this->json_encode( $output );
```

and in the ajax handler i did:--

```
// Setting the session value for the prices.
jQuery.session.set('price', data.price);
jQuery.session.set('price_for_two', data.price_for_two);
jQuery.session.set('price_for_three', data.price_for_three);
jQuery.session.set('price_for_retake', data.price_for_retake);
```

The above sets the session values for the different prices.

I could have also passed the `array` but I did this which is fine.